# Missing git tags when push to remote repository (e.g. Google Source Repositories)

Tags: git, tags, google-source-repositories

I have just set up a local git repo and replicated it to a remote repo, based upon a Google "Cloud Source Repository". This mostly worked fine, except that the tags haven't been replicated. I have some older google repos, built in the same way (as far as I can remember), that do have tags. So I'm not sure what is going on.

The process was to:

- create a local git repo (git 2.17.1 on an ubuntu 18.04 machine),
- add some files and commit them,
- add some tags along the lines of `git tag -a V1.0.0 -m "The initial working version"`,
- update and add some more files (this was for a training guide I'm writing for my team) and add more tags, and
- then set-up a google repo, connect to it via the Google SDK
  mechanism, and `git push --all google`.

All of which seems to have worked fine, except that there are no tags in the remote repo. The output of the git tags command is shown below, and I can see the tags fine in the gitk GUI. So the issue isn't with the local repo. The tags just haven't made it into Google's repos.

## Has anyone seen this issue before, or can suggest what I look at next?

```
$ git tag
V1.0.0
V1.0.1
V1.1.0
V2.0.0
```

The push output follows: no errors.

```
git push --all google
Counting objects: 25, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (20/20), done.
Writing objects: 100% (25/25), 5.03 KiB | 2.51 MiB/s, done.
Total 25 (delta 7), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (7/7)
To https://source.developers.google.com/p/<REDACTED>/r/git_test
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

Comment: Have you tried `git push --tags`?

Comment: Just tried it: worked like a charm! Bit surprised that **--all** doesn't actually mean **all**, and I'm pretty sure I didn't have to explicitly push tags before, but I guess things change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to John for pointing out what is expected behaviour! From [git-scm.com/book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging) "By default, the git push command doesn’t transfer tags to remote servers."

So you need an explicit: `git push --tags google` in my case, or  `git push --tags origin` in the typical case.